# Authenticate Xamarin windows phone 8.1 Apps Using Azure Active Directory (no Preview dlls)

Tags: azure, authentication, windows-phone-8, xamarin.forms, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

We are developing **Xamarin forms** windows phone 8.1 App  and we want to use Azure Active Directory for Authentication. (we are using Xamarin forms as in future we may develop app for ios, anroid)

We don't want to use any preview version of ADAL.  I saw lot examples which uses preview ADAL and nativeclient windows 8.1 app.

Can you please guide us? App should be using Xamarin forms(windows phone 8.1 silverlight) **not Nativeclient**.

Sharing some sample code or link would be great.

Thanks
Yog

Comment: Could you comment on why you don't want to use the Preview DLL's? And why don't you base the code in the examples you've read and change NativeClient for Xamarin code as needed? This is not a real programming question, flagged.

Comment: wouldn't this help https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/azure/active-directory/